# Dynamically replace drop down menu options jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down menu whose select options I would like to change on a click event.  The current select options should be removed and replaced with a new array of options.
Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aatSB/):

And here's another attempt at fixing it that doesn't work:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var dropdown = $('<select>');
            dropdown.options = function (data) {
                var self = this;
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    //how to remove the current elements
                }
                $.each(data, function (ix, val) {
                    var option = $('<option>').text(val);
                    data.push(option);
                });
                self.append(data)
            }
            dropdown.clear = function () {
                this.options([]);
            }
            var array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
            dropdown.options(array);
            $('body').append(dropdown);
            $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function (ix, val) {
                //should clear out the current options
                //and replace with the new array
                var newArray = ['four', 'five', 'six'];
                dropdown.clear();
                dropdown.options(newArray);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is change `append()` to `html()` since `html()` replaces existing content of element

```
 dropdown.options = function (data) {
            var self = this;
            $.each(data, function (ix, val) {
                var option = $('<option>').text(val).val(val);/* added "val()" also*/
                data.push(option);
            });
            self.html(data)
        }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aatSB/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: I fiddled around with this for far too long.  I knew I couldnt've been too far off, thanks @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

To clear the select use below code:

```
dropdown.empty();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/247z2/1/